# How do I get Codeception to open Firefox in laravel 5.1? Or How do I do acceptance testing with a SPA on laravel 5?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, laravel-5, reactjs, codeception

I'm trying to create acceptance tests to work with reactJS. I first got Codeception running fine then added react. Thats when I noticed that codeception doesn't have JS enabled. I've tried adding phantomJS: same problem. Since I can't debug phantomJS, I decided to try selenium so I can see it run in firefox. I've been working on this for days and Codeception **refuses** to open firefox like a normal selenium test.

Things your gonna ask:
- Yes, I run `codecept build` after every change.
- Yes I have `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.0.jar` running. Though that doesn't matter. There is no difference in the test whether I have it running or not.
- Yes I've tried `$I->waitForElement('#whatever')`. After like 20 seconds it dies.
- No, I **have** to use laravel

Here's my configuration:

acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://eagle.app/'
            browser: firefox #This does nothing. I literally changed it to `fart` and it didn't error. just same failed tests due to no JS
            window_size: 1024x768
            capabilities:
                webStorageEnabled: true
                javascriptEnabled: true
                firefox_binary: /Applications/Firefox.app
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

/tests/acceptance/AuthCest.php

```
<?php
//use \AcceptanceTester;

class AuthCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function register(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        // This should open firefox/selenium
        $I->executeInSelenium(function (Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
            $handles=$webdriver->getWindowHandles();
            $last_window = end($handles);
            $webdriver->switchTo()->window($last_window);
        });

        // This is my original test. I realize its not in executeInSelenium()
        // but I'm just showing you what works in non-SPA laravel apps (which doesn't work for me)
        $I->switchToWindow();
        $I->am('an anonymous user');
        $I->wantTo('Register');
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->wait(1);
        $I->see('Laravel 5'); #this is where it dies with react
        $I->click('REGISTER');
        $I->fillField(['name' => 'name'], 'testuser');
        $I->fillField(['name' => 'email'], 'test@user.com');
        $I->fillField(['name' => 'password'], 'testuserpass');
        $I->fillField(['name' => 'password_confirmation'], 'testuserpass');
        $I->click('Register', '#content form');
        $I->see('LOG OUT');
        $I->click('LOG OUT');
        $I->see('REGISTER');
        $I->click('LOG IN');
        $I->fillField(['name' => 'email'], 'test@user.com');
        $I->fillField(['name' => 'password'], 'testuserpass');
        $I->click('Login', '#content form');
        $I->see('LOG OUT');

    }
}
```

codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
        - Codeception\Extension\Recorder
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to open firefox manually, Codeception + Selenium does it automatically when you run ./codecept run acceptance

Also, make sure "firefox_binary" points to right path.